# MySQL server has gone away Error No: 2006

Tags: mysql, opencart

I need your help, friends.
I use Open Cart 3, and when I check my logs i view this error:

```
[11-Jan-2020 04:12:05 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Error: MySQL server has gone away<br />Error No: 2006<br />SELECT * FROM oc_currency in /home/nnhmetwhlxad/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php:40
Stack trace:
#0 /home/nnhmetwhlxad/public_html/system/library/db.php(45): DB\MySQLi->query('SELECT * FROM o...')
#1 /home/nnhmetwhlxad/public_html/system/library/cart/currency.php(10): DB->query('SELECT * FROM o...')
#2 /home/nnhmetwhlxad/public_html/catalog/controller/startup/startup.php(160): Cart\Currency->__construct(Object(Registry))
#3 /home/nnhmetwhlxad/storage2/modification/system/engine/action.php(79): ControllerStartupStartup->index()
#4 /home/nnhmetwhlxad/public_html/system/engine/router.php(67): Action->execute(Object(Registry))
#5 /home/nnhmetwhlxad/public_html/system/engine/router.php(46): Router->execute(Object(Action))
#6 /home/nnhmetwhlxad/public_html/system/framework.php(165): Router->dispatch(Object(Action), Object(Action))
#7 /home/nnhmetwhlxad/public_html/system/startup.php(104): require_once('/home/nnhmetwhl...')
#8 /ho in /home/nnhmetwhlxad/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 40
```

Comment: What do you mean when you check your logs ? 
I guess checking logs trigger some query and you might have really a lot of data in that table so query execution takes too long, you might want to change certain settings like max_allowed_packet=64M -> add this line to my.cnf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION I FOUND:**

Mysqli is controlled by your host, not by opencart itself.

Could have been a temporary issue as hosting companies do restart servers at various times.

This could also be a timeout issue when the server never gets the result from a MySQLI call because the process has stalled.

The latter can happen because the automatic currency update when in the admin backend,

> **Disable** the automatic currency update at `System > Settings > Local > Auto Update Currency` and then try again.

**NOTE:** Refresh your dashboard and the errors resolved. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL server has gone away (error 2006) has two main causes and solutions:

- Server timed out and closed the connection. To fix, check that wait_timeout mysql variable in your my.cnf configuration file is large enough.
- You may also need to increase the innodb_log_file_size mysql variable in your my.cnf configuration to for example 128MB or higher.
- Server dropped an incorrect or too large packet. If mysqld gets a packet that is too large or incorrect, it assumes that something has gone wrong with the client and closes the connection. To fix, you can increase the maximal packet size limit max_allowed_packet in my.cnf file, eg. set max_allowed_packet = 128M, then restart your MySQL server: sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart